# Log in using CasperJS not working, button greyed out

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, forms

I am trying to log into this web app with CasperJS.  I have filled out the form successfully, but cannot log in for some reason.  I have tried putting in wait times as well as clicking on the email/password fields.  When I screen capture after all of my operations, what I see is:
[image]

The log in button is greyed out and I am not sure why.  If anyone knows a work around to somehow log in to this website, here is the code I am using:

```
var links = [], linkHolder = [], result = '<p>';
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',

    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  true,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
         loadPlugins: true,         // use these settings
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.start('https://app.relateiq.com/', function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        casper.waitForSelector('form.sign-in-form input.ng-valid-email', function() {
            casper.evaluate(function(username, password) {
                document.querySelector('form.sign-in-form input.ng-valid-email').click();
                document.querySelector('form.sign-in-form input.ng-valid-email').value = username;
                document.querySelector('div.password-container input').click();
                document.querySelector('div.password-container input').value = password;
                this.wait(5000, function() {
                    document.querySelector('form.sign-in-form button.btn-primary').click(); 
                });
            }, 'myemail@myemail.com', 'myassociatedpassword');
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(5000, function() {
            this.capture('./relateScreen.png');
            this.echo("Page Title " + this.getTitle());
        })
    })
});
```

How could I work around this seemingly disabled log in button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites are written for people who type in their information into the fields the website provides. When you use `inputElement.value = "myValue";`, you're setting the value of an input element, but that doesn't mean that the accompanying events are triggered that denote a change in the value. You would have to trigger a change event somehow.

PhantomJS provides the [`sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function which actually provides native actions. When this function is used, the website cannot distinguish from a normal user (aside from typing speed and patterns).

CasperJS provides a wrapper around that with [`sendKeys()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#sendkeys):

```
casper.sendKeys('form.sign-in-form input.ng-valid-email', 'myemail@myemail.com');
casper.sendKeys('div.password-container input', 'myassociatedpassword');
casper.click('form.sign-in-form button.btn-primary');
```

Now you don't need to use `evaluate()` to set those fields in the page context anymore. Also, you can't use `casper.wait()` inside of the page context, because only the functions in the [clientutils module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html) are exposed inside of the page context.

Comment: Ohh, I suspected something like this may be happening, thank you for the great answer